# What are the best and optimum ways to handle client side global error in a application where it's built in angular, angularjs and jQuery technologies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, error-handling, runtime-error

I did lots of research to implement this but found out that each technology has their own mechanism to handle the global error, but I want a common mechanism to handle unexpected error for all the technologies and frameworks being used in the application.

Later I came to the solution to handle global error using javascript **onerror** method.

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
alert('Error: ' + errorMsg + ' Script: ' + url + ' Line: ' + lineNumber
+ ' Column: ' + column + ' StackTrace: ' +  errorObj);
}
```

Is this a better way or should I use different error handling for each and every frameworks/Technologies being used in the application?

Please suggest?

Comment: Angular4 has a global error handler that you can hook into

Comment: use `ErrorHandler` where is from `@angular/core` and implement. It provide the method ` handleError`. check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@angular/core` API for error handling.

Please refer to this example:

https://medium.com/@amcdnl/global-error-handling-with-angular2-6b992bdfb59c